# Record meetings with Google Mini or Amazon Alexa?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, google-home

I've been asked to develop an action for either `Google Mini` or `Amazon Alexa` that allows the device to record the audio from a meeting (no time limit) and send that script to the meeting-participants.

Is it possible to record audio for extended periods of time with these devices?

I'm aware that both the `Mini` and `Alexa` are 'always recording' but it seems they just overwrite local storage. As an alternative to recording for an extended period, is it possible then to output these recordings to a web-service and concatenate them into one file on the back-end?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question as defined in the Help Center.

Comment: @Rob Where should such a question be asked?

Comment: I don't know of any stackexchange site that would accept this as a question.

Comment: How isn't it a programming question? Clearly it's about the scope of the SDKs for either Alexa or Google Mini.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the devices aren't "always *recording*". They are "always *listening*". Anything that is stored in memory is for a very short period of time - just long enough to see if it is the triggering hotword and/or to forward anything else said once triggered.

There is no authorized way for you to tap into this mic.

Similarly, neither device gives you access to the audio recorded through a server - they just send you text transcripts. Google does let you listen to what was recorded on their servers, but you can't access it as a third-party.

On the Alexa, there probably isn't much you can do. It won't forward text that doesn't match one of the Intents, and open-ended text is deprecated and discouraged.

With the Assistant, using the Action SDK, you can get most of the text spoken. But there are a few caveats. Although you'll get text, you won't get who spoke the text, nor the timing of things (was it spoken slowly? quickly? was there a long pause between a question and response?). The Assistant will also send things in batches, either when it thinks you've said "enough" or when it thinks you've finished what you're saying, and your server then needs to send back a response (which could be as simple as a very short audio file), but while it is "processing", you'll miss everything that was said.

In short - while possible, the current hardware and system software is unsuited to this sort of application.

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions as defined in the Help Center. Not all questions can or should be answered here. Avoid answering questions which solicit opinions rather than facts. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Cheers @Prisoner, I'll look into alternatives.

Comment: @Pembroke did you ever find any solution to this